# What are the security risks of rendering a user-input Django template?

Tags: django, security, django-templates

For an internal company webapp, I would like to have users be able to edit a Django template that is stored as a model which is then used to render a form email, with an on-screen preview. What would be the security risks in doing this?

Comment: Messing with non HTML code inside the template can break it and your application can raise exceptions, for example.

Comment: @PauloBu - thanks, yes, I'm handling exceptions. In any case, I'm concerned about security right now. Do broken templates create any security risk?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind. Templates are rendered by Django template engine. They only have access to the objects in the context, if no object is sensible (like a db cursor or something like that) then probably is kind of safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It entirely depends on what data you're giving your template access to in its context. The two areas this is likely to be determined are:

- context processors (as defined in your settings.py file)
- views, where you pass context data to the render function

If you pass things like your settings object to your context (which shouldn't be done, but frequently is) then users will be able to get stuff like your database credentials.

Also, if you're running in debug mode (which, again, you shouldn't be doing in prod), forcing an exception can result in a debug page being shown which contains sensitive data.

If you are just using django's default context processors, and are not putting any sensitive data into the context via the view, you should be fairly safe so far as security goes.